# Java - Retrieving User account application is running under

Tags: java

I've got a web application running on a Windows Server 2008 machine.  The app is running under spring tcserver.

When the server group setup the box they created a service account that I run the application under.  They also created a admin account for me.

Within the app through java it's executing a web service.

Most of the time the app works fine.  Every once in a while if I'm logged onto the server with the admin account I'll get a HTTP status code 403 as a response when using the app.  After a while (sometimes 10 mins, sometimes 30 mins) it will start working again.  Talking to other developers @ work they're saying that it's an issue on the remote server that the web service resides on.  I've sent the errors to the owner of the webservice to see if they see any issues from their side.  Being that it's only occurred when I'm logged on to the server I'm skeptical whether it could be somehow using my profile instead.  Through task manager I can see the app running under the correct account.

So long story short, is there a way to retrieve the actual account the app is running under.  When I try System.getproperty("user.name") this just returns system.  It returns that the times when I get the error & also when it's working properly.  Is there another method of retrieving the user account.

Also let me know if you think I'm wasting my time & that you also think it's an issue on the remote server.

Any other suggestions please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by user account ? how do you differ it from owner user of the jvm ?

Comment: I should've phrased the question differently.  I do mean the owner user of the jvm.

Comment: who do you see owner in your task manager

Comment: In the task manager I see java running under the specific account that was created for the App.

Comment: try `new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem().getName()`

Comment: I believe you are going in a wrong direction. You should look at the app server logs and application logs for clues. If you don't get any clues from them get your application developers debug it. You may have to find a way to predictably reproduce the problem though. Else you can't verify it if your developer says it is fixed. How do you know?!

Comment: I did look @ the server logs, but other than the forbidden message it didn't have much information.  The statement I receive the message on is when I call the web service.  I'm using log4j for logging I'll set it up in DEBUG mode to see if it gives any more details. thx